How do I create an =IF() statement on Excel where the logical test is tested against a range of variables?
I am trying to create a new variable (STEM) that = 1 if the number in each cell for B matches one of the 536 numbers in column K. I know about =IF(OR()), but I would really rather not input each of the individual 536 values as separate conditions, and that is beyond the condition maximum that the =IF(OR()) accepts...
So is there any way to make it so that if the cells in column B match any of the values in column K, the new variable STEM = 1, and 0 otherwise?
An image of the first 34 rows of the table I am working with.

I tried, for D2, =IF(B2=K2:K537, 1, 0). That did not yield the desired result, since the value in B2 (1.0999) is in column K but D2 yielded 0.

Should be easy using XMATCH() and ISNUMBER() --> Try: =IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2,$K$2:$K$537)),1,0) if you don;t have XMATCH() then replace it with MATCH() function.

Or =--OR(B2=K$2:K$537)

Try using XMATCH() or MATCH() function.


=IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2,$K$2:$K$537)),1,0) 



XMATCH() function matches the particular and returns the position.
Using ISNUMBER() to confirm whether it is a number or not.
Using IF() to return the TRUE and FALSE values based on the above.


Alternatively, can use one of the followings as well:
=IF(1-ISNA(XMATCH(B2,$K$2:$K$536)),1,0)


Or,
=IF(1-ISNA(MATCH(B2,$K$2:$K$536,0)),1,0)


Or, Bit shorter i think:
=SUM(N(B2=$K$2:$K$536))



Thank you very much! This worked quite well.
